# Селектор левых соседей

Tags: css

Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно разместить стиль для соседей, которые находится слева от элемента. В моём случае, нужно, чтобы `ul` элемент красил элемент `a` в красный.

Вот мой html код:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Конечно, у меня у второго меню стиль `position:absolute` и можно просто сделать вот так:

```css
ul > li > ul {position:absolute}
ul > li > ul ~ a {color: red}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li><ul>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Но в html это выглядит странно.

Простите за такой идиотский вопрос, конечно, можно добавлять какой-то класс пунктам, которые имеют второе меню, но хотелось бы обойтись без этого

Comment: В css нет селектора позволяющего выбирать соседние элементы слева.

Comment: @Grundy, и это плохо

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Выбрать предыдущего соседа с помощью селектора [невозможен средствами CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817801/1548895). И даже в [черновике CSS4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#combinators) на момент написания этой возможности нет.

Поэтому да, только

1. Через класс для соответствующего элемента. Просто добавить класс в разметку вручную.
2. Псевдоклассы `nth-child` и подобные, если это подходит для данного случая.
3. **Инвертирование разметки (расположение элементов в обратном порядке в разметке) и применение flexbox.**

   Мы можем инвертировать элементы либо через `row-reverse`/`column-reverse`, либо через свойство `order`.

   Допустим есть элементы `first` и `second`. И нужно добавить селектор, когда `first` перед `second`. Для этого нужно их поменять местами, затем применить селектор `second + first`.

   Первый способ (предпочтительный): Затем присваиваем контейнеру `flex-direction: row-reverse;` или `flex-direction: column-reverse;` в зависимости от разметки:

   ```css
   .flex {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row-reverse;
   }

   .second + .first {
     color: red;
     margin-right: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="flex">
     <div class="second">
       Second
     </div>
     <div class="first">
       First
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   Второй способ: Затем делаем `order` `second` меньше `first`:

   ```css
   .flex {
     display: flex;
   }

   .second + .first {
     color: red;
     margin-right: 10px;
   }

   .second {
     order: 2;
   }

   .first {
     order: 1;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="flex">
     <div class="second">
       Second
     </div>
     <div class="first">
       First
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Через JavaScript. Добавление класса или CSS-свойств через JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

Т. к. в вопросе ничего не сказано про интерактивность, предположу, что надо просто покрасить все ссылки, за которыми скрывается вложенное меню. При имеющейся разметке это делается очень легко, поскольку ссылка либо идёт последней, либо за ней есть ul.

```css
a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
  color: red;
}

a:last-child:link, a:last-child:visited, a:last-child:hover, a:last-child:active {
  color: blue;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая возможность выделение элементов слева:

Суть в том, что, с помощью `display: flex;` и свойства `flex-direction: row-reverse;` у контейнера, вы можете изменить порядок элементов на обратный и тогда все выделения css правых элементов будут выделять левые элементы.

less/saas:

```
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .elem {
    background: red;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
  }
  .elem:hover, .elem.active {
    background: blue;
    & ~ .elem {
      background: blue;
    }
  }
```

css:

```
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .elem {
    background: red;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
  }
  .elem:hover {
    background: blue;
  }

  .elem:hover ~ .elem {
      background: blue;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте задать свойства через псевдокласс :has(), который отображает элемент в том случае, если любой из селекторов, переданный в качестве параметра, соответствует хотя бы одному элементу.

```css
li:has(>ul)>a {color: red}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">Пункт 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```