# Как выбрать предыдущий элемент (CSS)

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Приветствую.
В примере я использовал `input type="radio"` для выбора "показать" "закрыть" некий блок. Как сделать так, чтобы активный `radio` изменил фон, т.е. `lightgreen` сменился на `green`, с красным получилось (цвета наоборот правда, но это не страшно), потому что он последующий элемент, а зеленый получается, как предыдущий элемент, так вот как выбрать чтобы предыдущий элемент менял фон при `:checked`? Спасибо!

```css
body{z-index:10;positioin:relative;text-align:center;}
input{display:none;}/*радио кнопки*/
label[for="radio-1"]{background:lightgreen;}
label[for="radio-2"]{background:pink;}
label{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}
label:hover{opacity:0.6;}
label:active{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
.block{
  width:600px;
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  left:28%;
}
#radio-1:checked ~ .block{display:block;} .block{display:none;}
#radio-1:checked ~ label{background:red;}
```

```html
<label class="green" for="radio-1">OPEN<sup>(chckd)</sup></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1" checked="checked">
<label class="red" for="radio-2">CLOSE</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2">
      <!-- -->
      <!-- -->
    <div class="block">
       <fieldset>
        <legend>HEADER</legend>
        <h1>TEXT-HEADER #1
        <strong>...some text</strong></h1>
        </fieldset>

       </div>
```

Comment: Именно в такой формулировке в явном виде - невозможно, но есть хитрые способы, как имитировать такое поведение. [ссылка(eng)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector), [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609133/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: @АлександрБелинский, не думаю, что правильно более частные вопросы закрывать как дубликат вопроса с решением "невозможно".

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> input{display:none;}/*радио кнопки*/
> ```

Сами инпуты всё равно скрыты, поэтому ты можешь поставить их в любое место в разметке. Надо их поставить раньше и, возможно, выше тех элементов, на которые они должны влиять, а затем использовать селекторы следующих видов:

```
#chk-i:checked ~ .smth-i
#chk-i:checked ~ .root .smth-i
```

В твоём случае получается так:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:5px;
  margin-top:20px;
  display:inline-block;
}

label:hover {
  opacity:0.6;
}

#radio-1:checked ~ label[for="radio-1"] { background: green; }
#radio-2:checked ~ label[for="radio-2"] { background: red; }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2">
<label class="green" for="radio-1">OPEN<sup>(chckd)</sup></label>
<label class="red" for="radio-2">CLOSE</label>
```

PS: В css нельзя обратиться к более раннему элементу. Пока единственное исключение - псевдокласс `:focus-within`, но он тебе не помежет.

Comment: это отличный способ, не знаю почему сам не догадался...спасибо!

Comment: "Сами инпуты всё равно скрыты, поэтому ты можешь поставить их в любое место в разметке. " 
поправлю, абы где не поставить, в пределах блока где находятся label, иначе условия работать не будут radio-1:checked ~ label[for="radio-1"] { background: green; }

Comment: @VictorKas, можно и выше лейблов поставить. Селектор поменяется на `radio-1:checked ~ * label[for="radio-1"]` (правда звёздочку лучше заменить на что-то поточнее).

Comment: @VictorKas, какой такой пример?

Comment: я же удалил пост...не стал продолжать, примеры писать и т.д) не удобно тут

Comment: Да ты дважды незаконченный комментарий запостил. Второй удалил, но мне ж всё равно интересно :) Пример можно на jsfiddle сделать.

Answer (score 0):

вот например в таком варианте условие работать не будет, пока инпут находится за пределами блока label
* да, если использовать такое условие

## radio-1:checked ~* label{background:red;} - работает

```css
input{margin-bottom:20px;}
label{
  border:1px solid orange;
  padding:10px;
}
#radio-1:checked ~ label{background:red;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1">
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2">
<div>
  <label for="radio-1">radio-1</label>
  <label for="radio-2">radio-2</label>
</div>
```