# Как при помощи CSS обратиться к родителю тэга?

Tags: css, css3

Допустим, есть код:
HTML:

```
<label><input type = "radio"></label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
 visibility: hidden;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked{
}
```

Теперь вопрос:
Как мне писать стили для тэга `label`, в `input[type="radio"]:checked{}` ?
То есть, я хочу присвоить родительскому тэгу `label` определенные стили при нажатии на `<input type = "radio">`.

Answer (score 0):

При помощи CSS ни как. Вот, [почитай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609133/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9). DOM дерево работает в этом случае только вниз, к потомкам. Используй JS

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент такой возможности, но обещают ввести в 4 версии has(), можно выбрать следующий за:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: blue;
} 
label {
  padding: .5em
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="test" name="radio"/>
<label for="test">Test label</label>
<input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio"/>
<label for="test2">Test label2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Напиши маленький скрипт, который будет добавлять или удалять класс. Например, вот так:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().tooggleClass('checked');
})
```